# jekyll post loop not working on home page. Showing code as it is

Tags: html, github, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I want to show latest posts in my bolg.html page. So i used Liquid syntax

But when i used the liquid shown below and run locally, the page shows the code as it is and it doesn't fetch posts from my _posts folder.

The liquid syntax is given below:

[liquid syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdAl9.jpg)

and then the out put is as given below

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB4CW.jpg)

Please help me. Also i'am using a template called **Triangle** from bootstrap. and i'am hosting on github.

Comment: Do you have liquid installed locally? If you don't, you will need to do that, installing it via command line  `gem install liquid` as explained [here](http://liquidmarkup.org/)

Comment: still **not** working.

Comment: Weird... I'll give a better look at your code and compare to mine later and if I find something useful I'll get back to you.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking, how are you running `jekyll serve`? Try running it by this command : `bundle exec jekyll serve --safe --watch --baseurl ""` and see if you get an error. This is the safest way to test how GitHub is going to render your Jekyll site.

Comment: Post your code as text please. And if you have a repository url it's even better to try to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I think I know what's wrong. Your loop is not working because you said `{% for blogpost in site.posts%}` and then you call the loop by `post` and not `blogpost`. Try changing the `for` loop to:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
```

and you should be fine!

If this answer is correct or useful, please mark it! Thanks! ;)

Comment: That does't matter at all. But i changed "blogpost" to "post"  and still i have the problem.

Comment: Would you please post you code as text here so I can copy it and paste into a document in order to run some tests? Also, can you include your posts yaml front matter?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late but I just had a similar issue.

I originally had this in my `default.html`

```
---
page.title: My Blog
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{{ page.title }} | My Blog - Musings of a Software Developer from Norwich</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'/assets/main.css' | prepend: site.baseurl}}">
</head>   
<body>
    {% include nav.html %}

    <div class="content">
        {{ page.content }}
    </div>
    <script src="{{'/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
    <script src="{{'/node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
    <script src="{{'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and in my blog.html, I had

```
---
title: Blog
layout: default
---

<h1>Latest Posts</h1>

<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### Answer

I noticed that when I removed the layout from the frontmatter, then the loop was running correctly, so I put my layout back in and it stopped working. Then on closer comparison with another site I was doing, I noticed in my layout I had `{{ page.content }}`. So I updated this to just be `{{ content }}` and hey presto, I got my theme and it looping over the blog posts like I wanted it too. Hopefully this might help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

I'm really late to the party but better late than never eh?

By looking at the screenshots you've posted it seems you're using `{{ page.content }}` in your layout template as liquid tags don't seem to be rendering as you expect them to. Maybe you need to use `{{ content }}` instead so your content renders correctly before being outputted to the page?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting the index.html in the root directory and creating an index.md. After this, everything worked as expected!